# R: Regular Expressions in R - Multi string extraction

Tags: regex, r

Say I have a string like this:

```
[1] "<u>Degradation:</u> AGL, PGM1, PGM2, PGM3, PYGL, PYGM.<br>\n"
```

I want to extract each of these gene IDs into a vector. I could probably use strsplit in this case, but I want to do this with regex as I will later have more complex cases. Say I want to extract all strings that contain '[A-Z0-9]{2,} (if it contains any combinations of at least two capital letters and numbers then I want it).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stringr` package makes this kind of thing pretty easy.

```
> library(stringr)
> x <- "<u>Degradation:</u> AGL, PGM1, PGM2, PGM3, PYGL, PYGM.<br>\n"
> str_extract_all(x, '[A-Z0-9]{2,}')
[[1]]
[1] "AGL"  "PGM1" "PGM2" "PGM3" "PYGL" "PYGM"
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) strapply**

`strapply` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) can do that:

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- "<u>Degradation:</u> AGL, PGM1, PGM2, PGM3, PYGL, PYGM.<br>\n"
strapply(x, "[A-Z0-9]{2,}", c)
```

**2) strapplyc**

Also there is a high speed version specialized to use `c` in the development repo.

```
library(gsubfn)
# download and read in strapplyc
source("http://gsubfn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/R/strapplyc.R")
strapplyc(x, "[A-Z0-9]{2,}")
```

Also see this example of extracting all the words from James Joyce's Ulysses [here](https://groups.google.com/group/corpling-with-r/msg/b85f7ff917cccb5d?dmode=source&output=gplain&noredirect&pli=1) .

**Choosing**

`strapply` has a lot of variations to it so if flexibility is most important then it might be a good choice.  On the other hand, `strapplyc` might be particularly useful if your strings are very long so that speed is important and you only need to extract strings.